# Rails 4.2, Paperclip gem. Failing to attach .docx type, reads content_type as 'application/zip' despite MIME type being registered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I've registered a MIME Type to allow Paperclip to read a `.docx` file's content_type as `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`.

However in tests the content_type is still being read as `application/zip`.

Any idea why? To make things more frustrating, the `.pptx` and `.xlsx` mime types *have* been registered, those tests pass (urgh).

**config/initializers/mime_types.rb**

```
Mime::Type.register 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', :docx
Mime::Type.register 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation', :pptx
Mime::Type.register 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', :xlsx
```

**app/models/attachment.rb**

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include FormatFile

  # Constants:
  VALID_FILE_NAMES = [/[^a-z0-9\-]+/i].freeze
  VALID_IMAGE_TYPES = %w[image/jpeg image/jpg image/png image/x-icon image/bnp].freeze
  VALID_CONTENT_TYPES = %w[
    image/jpeg
    image/jpg
    image/gif
    image/png
    image/bmp
    image/x-icon
    text/plain
    text/csv
    application/xml
    application/pdf
    application/msword
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template
    application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12
    application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12
    application/vnd.ms-excel
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template
    application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12
    application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12
    application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12
    application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12
  ].freeze

  # Associations:
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true

  # Paperclip attachments
  has_attached_file :attachment,
                    styles:      {
                      medium:   ['300x300#', :png],
                      thumb:    ['100x100#', :png],
                      original: ['500x500>', :png]
                    },
                    default_url: '/images/:style/missing.png',
                    url:         '/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:hash.:extension',
                    path:        ':rails_root/public:url',
                    hash_secret: '623629947a471569fe9808ab386f6e866abde5f582485beaa24fa12032b28a21b6ee94c018fe531484bb438a7376d4a00b4bc35598de34c01f0e40b1dbb37df5'

  # Validations:
  validates_attachment  :attachment,
                        content_type: {content_type: VALID_CONTENT_TYPES},
                        file_name:    {matches: VALID_FILE_NAMES},
                        size:         {in: 0..5.megabytes}
  validates_with AttachmentPresenceValidator, attributes: :attachment

  # Callbacks:
  before_post_process :skip_all_non_images
  before_validation do
    sanitize_filename attachment_file_name
  end

  # Don't shrink and create different styles for anything which isn't an image
  def skip_all_non_images
    VALID_IMAGE_TYPES.include?(attachment_content_type)
  end
end
```

Thanks for the help.

**Edit:**

As per the link provided by bkunzi01 I tried the following code. It had no effect, `.docx` files still fail validation whilst `.pptx` and `.xlsx` pass.

*config/application.rb*

```
  Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = {
      docx: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
      pptx: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
      xlsx: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    }
```

Comment: Paperclip has a feature called filetype spoofing that some browsers break (like pdfs being read as octet-stream etc.) which may be playing a role.  Good writeup here: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/prevent-spoofing-with-paperclip

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it hasn't worked. I read through the article regardless and it increased my understanding.

Comment: This may not be relevant at all - but last week I ran into a similar issue with the newest PaperClip gem where it wouldn't read the file as a `csv`, and after hours the issue was with files without `.csv` in the file name at the end were, not being read as a csv, even if the content_type was set as `text/csv`. I had to ensure the file ended with `.csv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the new version of paperclip was causing this issue. Downgrading to version 4.3.1 should resolve your issue

Comment: If Patrick accepts your answer, I'll award you the bounty. Aside: Have you reported this issue to the developers?

Comment: Agi - No I haven't yet.  I figured this out today and will submit an issue later today.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe post the link to the bug report here